# border-radius not working in ion-cards

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to add a blank space of color #F1F1F1 before the first card.
And also want to add the border-radius on the ion cards.
The image is as below.
[image]

In the image the curves in the left and the right side is of ion cards and above that is the space between the header and the card.

By adding `section` in the below code adds the space but the cards border-radius is not dislayed well.
How can I achieve this?

**.html**

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
Ionic Cards
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

<section class="blankspace"></section>

<ion-card class="card">
   //card content
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

**.css**

```
.blankspace {
border-bottom: 5px solid #F1f1f1;
}

.card {

border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: .card {

border-radius: 5px;
overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: ion-card {border-radius: 5px;} Try this

Answer (score 4):

HTML code:

```
<ion-card style="border-radius: 25px;">
```

It´s working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is working, but isn't clipping the content, try this

```
.card {
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: bottom radius are working but top radius are not working for me

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your code now, maybe the blank space is above it? try to isolate the card